# Turning on ibus in Ubuntu 16.10—and using it for text emoji?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, ibus, emoji

I've recently switched to Ubuntu from Mac, and now I'm trying to make an excellent dropdown menu that displays text emoji (like shruggie ¯_(ツ)_/¯ or tableflip (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻) as I type. (I've already—delightfully—got the compose key working, as you can see by the sweet emdashes I've got in this sentence.) A helpful friend suggested using ibus with table input method, and linked me to [this github repo](https://github.com/salty-horse/ibus-uniemoji), with the cryptic note "­add tableflip to custom.json before compiling."

Well, I've installed ibus and made it launch when I log in. Now, [this how-to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ibus) suggests that I ought to be able to find something called "ibus preferences" to start using it, but I can't locate it to turn ibus on!

So that's step one of my question. Step two is figuring out how to use that repo. But even just getting past step one would be awesome. (I mostly included the text-emoji wrinkle because I know emoji questions are asked here with some regularity and figured it might be interesting/useful...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBus runs by default on Ubuntu 16.10, so there should be no need to install it or do anything special to make it launch at login. To add IBus input methods, use *System Settings -> Text Entry*, not IBus Preferences. (If you for some reason still would need to access the latter, you can use the command `ibus-setup`.

As regards ibus-uniemoji: Download the ZIP archive, unzip it and install it with `sudo make install`. It should then be available as an input source in *Text Entry* next time you log in.

Comment: Πολυτονιψ Γρεεκ ςορκσ!  Looks like that works! So now I can ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ to my heart's delight. Thank you so much for your help!

The only remaining issue: when I try to edit the .json file to add tableflips, the whole thing breaks and I'm not 100% sure why. I'll take a lap and come back to it tomorrow—I'm probably just missing something obvious.

Comment: @flourish: I'm afraid I can't help you there. If you need help with modifying the thing, I'd recommend that you ask a new question which focuses on the particular issue you are having.

Comment: I will once I'm sure that I haven't just been overlooking something! Thank you so much, Gunnar. You've been a huge help and very welcoming to a newbie.